Password Guesser Enumerator Tool (Password Recovery)
Are there any tools that can be used to enumerate all possible combinations of a narrowly-defined set of possible passwords to aid in password recovery?
I encrypted a file using symmetric encryption with a long passphrase. I forgot the password.
I know the password consists of N parts and I know there are only M possible different combinations for each of the N parts. I want to try each one, but writing it out manually is a lot of work.
For example, say I have a password with 3 parts (N=3):

[part 1][part2][part 3]

I know that "part 1" is a type of pet. There are only 2 possibilities for part 1 (M=2). It could be "dog" or "cat".
I know that "part 2" is a type of clothing. There are only 5 possibilities for part 2 (M=5). It could be "shirt" or "pants" or "socks" or "jacket" or "underwear".
I know that "part 3" is a type of meal. There are only 3 possibilities for part 3 (M=3). It could be "breakfast" or "lunch" or "dinner".
This is just an example. In reality, I may have passwords with N=20 and M between 2-100. In such a password, the possible enumerations are very difficult to compile and test manually.
I'm looking for a tool to help me with this, so that I can use the information that I know about the possible passwords and feed it into a tool that will output a list of all possible combinations, which I can then iteratively try to decrypt the file.
Is there a tool to assist in password recovery for when you can't fully remember the entire password, but you have a good idea of what it might be in specific different parts of the password?

You could write a simple program using python or some other scripting tool to create a list of all possible password permutations.  Then, use a tool like Hashcat or John The Ripper to try each password in the list.

"Is there a tool?" is a plain ol' software recommendation. Chatgpt can take your explanation and suggest a python script.

hashcat's companion tool combinatorX, available in hashcat-utils, will do this.
$ cat list1.txt
the
quick

$ cat list2.txt
brown
fox

$ cat list3.txt
jumped
over

$ combinatorX -1 list1.txt -2 list2.txt -3 list3.txt
thebrownjumped
thebrownover
thefoxjumped
thefoxover
quickbrownjumped
quickbrownover
quickfoxjumped
quickfoxover

Common use cases are supported:

separators can also be specified globally or per position (including beginning and end)
sessions can be resumed/restored
work can be chunked / divided (like hashcat's skip/limit parameters)
maximum length and maximum repeated words per string can be specified

One quirk: if more than two lists are needed, none of them can be the  same file on disk. If you need to use the same list more than once, copy it to a new file.
